# DC power filter curicut

Tags: voltage, dc, wireless, telephone, voltage-source

I have a problem in powering my wireless Panasonic landline telephone. It works on 9v power with a transformer that work on 220v and gives as output 9v and it works fine with this way. I try to power it on 12v battery using a circuit that transfer 12v tp 9v with 1Amp
But the sound of the telephone speaker has an annoying noise i don't know way. So i need a help to fix this problem. I tried to use a capastior for smoothing the DC current but i didn't get any better.

Comment: What is your circuit for regulating 9V from 12V?

Comment: Using L7810CV regulator

Comment: You do realize that a L78**10**CV is a 10V regulator, not 9V, don't you ... ?

Comment: I use it as already sampled circuit but i test the output it's 9.2

Comment: it's 9.2 because 10v isn't enough headroom from 12v to achive a regulated output. use a proper rating and you won't have noise-producing oscillations.

Comment: What is a problem rating !,

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Also, giving the regulator you are using isn't the same as providing the circuit.  You mentioned adding a cap - where and what value?  But as others noted, that regulator is not appropriate because the voltage is too high and the dropout voltage is also too high.  To recommend an appropriate regulator we would also need to know the max current draw.  Have you measured that?

Comment: Look for a DC-DC buck converter that can supply 9V output at 1.5A with 10-16V input. This will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 7809 it would probably work as the battery voltage start somewhere above 13 volts and when you start to hear that annoying noise again the it's time to charge the battery.

Comment: 7809 but still there is a noise even when battery is full

Comment: Have you tried caps.

Comment: Yes i try even with conductor